# How to put 2 parameters on onclick using php

Tags: javascript, php

im having problem getting the value of a two input textbox using an onclick function.

```
<?php foreach ($showItems as $items) { ?>       
<tr>
    <td><?php if(!empty($items['ItemCode'])) echo $items['ItemCode'], ' '; ?><input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $items['ItemCode']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><img src="" /></td>
    <td><?php if(!empty($items['Name'])) echo $items['Name'], ' '; ?></td>
    <td><?php if(!empty($items['Price'])) echo $items['Price'], ' '; ?></td>
    <td><?php if(!empty($items['Description'])) echo $items['Description'], ' '; ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="3" size="2" onblur='if(this.value==""){this.value=1;}'  /></td>
            <td ><input type="submit" value="Add to Registry" onClick="addRegistry(<?php echo $items['ItemCode'];  ?>, document.getElementById('qty').value;)"></td>                    
</tr>               
<?php } ?>
```

**javascript script:**

```
function addRegistry(pid, qty){
    alert(qty);
    document.form.pid.value=pid;
    document.form.command.value='add';
    document.form.submit();
}
```

**php script:**

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
 $qty = $_POST['qty'];

 //echo $qty;
 $customerid = $_SESSION['id'];
 $pid=$_REQUEST['pid'];
// echo $pid;
 $admin->addToRegistry($pid, $customerid, $qty);
 header('location:registryCart.php');
}
```

how do i get the two values so that i can insert it to my database, i was able to get the itemcode, but i cant get the value of the quantity.

Comment: This is a very convoluted way of posting a form. There is no need whatsoever for JavaScript to do what you are doing.

Comment: You're creating duplicate IDs in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: It's not working because there are multiple inputs with `id="qty"`. `document.getElementById('qty')` will just find the first one, not the one next to the submit button you clicked on.

Comment: hi barmar.pls disregard the input hidden.

Comment: is there a way i can put it like this, onClick="addRegistry(<?php echo $items['ItemCode'];  ?>, <?php $_POST['qty'] ?>

Comment: `$_POST` is a PHP variable, it's only visible on the server after the form is submitted, it can't be used in Javascript on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$counter` variable which will increment and differentiate each input `id`

```
  <?php
    $counter=1;
 foreach ($showItems as $items) { ?>       
    <tr>
        <td><?php if(!empty($items['ItemCode'])) echo $items['ItemCode'], ' '; ?><input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $items['ItemCode']; ?>" /></td>
        <td><img src="" /></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($items['Name'])) echo $items['Name'], ' '; ?></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($items['Price'])) echo $items['Price'], ' '; ?></td>
        <td><?php if(!empty($items['Description'])) echo $items['Description'], ' '; ?></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty-<?php echo $counter; ?>" maxlength="3" size="2" onblur='if(this.value==""){this.value=1;}'  /></td>
                <td ><input type="submit" value="Add to Registry" onClick="addRegistry(<?php echo $items['ItemCode'];  ?>, document.getElementById('qty-<?php echo $counter; ?>').value;)"></td>                    
    </tr>               
    <?php
    $counter++;
 } ?>
```